# Making raster layer with shortest distance of each cell to roads using QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, distance

I have a road shp (or raster) layer, and I'd like to make a new raster layer of each cell is  filled with the distance to the nearest road.

Is it possible to compute the layer using QGIS with some function or plugin ?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this by first rasterizing the road network using the GDAL tool `Rasterize (vector to raster)` from the QGIS processing toolbox using a desired resolution. In a second step you apply the GDAL tool `Proximity (raster distance)` that can be found in the same processing algorithm collection.